# 'Whole lotta voting!

Tags: discussion

When our exciting graduation takes place, most of us will be faced with the harsh drawback that the probationary privilege levels will rise to their normal levels. So everybody loses privileges! Meh!

#### Counteract this by voting!

Do this: You know how sometimes from a question, you go back up to the questions link, or maybe back to one of the tags, or to a hot network question? Well, every once in a while, if you read a particularly nice question or answer, click their user page! Give another one a shot. *Don't be too fast or mechanical or anything. There are vote-fraud protection scripts in place. Vote the post up or down (or comment) on its own merits.*

Do this: Go to your favorite tag, and browse from the *oldest* page *backwards*. Some neglected gems back there, friends!

Do this: Get some voting badges. Vox Populi, Electorate. Shiny, shiny!

Do this: Vote on a proposed site name. I know, I know. They've already picked one. But *you need the practice!*

Do this: Keep your eyes peeled for nascent moderators, gonna be some voting pretty soon!

Do this: Post More ideas below.

Comment: We have quite a number of high rep users who haven't exactly worn out the voting buttons.

Comment: Cutoff for moderators on SO is 10K.  Voting will only benefit high-but-not-sufficient scorers within shouting distance of that number.

Comment: I think we're comparably bad at voting, and that there are further benefits. Getting people to be involved by more encouragement is one. We should, like droog is saying, of course not vote blindly, but there sure are quality questions and answers out there that deserve more love.

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude My hope (which may be futile) is that everyone could rise enough to stay at their current level.

Answer (score 6):

I hate to be the guy to shoot down an idea that sounds good, but... please reconsider. From what I understand, SE's features are usually based on the some kind of consensus that the features work best this way. The fact that it's easier to become a moderator in Beta is probably because the website is still young, and many people are not yet familiar with the rules for what's on topic and what isn't. Hence, more moderators are needed. Once you've shown that you *are* familiar with the rules, you're fit to be a moderator in Beta, so that you can help others in becoming more familiar with the rules as well.

Once the site goes live, there needs to be a higher reputation requirement, because it's more important for all moderators to always make the right decisions. A beta is meant as a place where things can go wrong, and they can be fixed along the road. On a live website, we should aim to have a moderator team that knows exactly what to do, and makes very few mistakes.

**Disclaimer: all of this is just my own speculation.**

Even if *these* are not the reasons, I am sure there are other ones. In the end, voting should not be done in order to achieve any kind of goal. The only purpose for upvoting things should be to make good questions & answers float to the top, and to encourage people to post more good questions & answers. If we vote purely in order to reach certain goals quickly, we're basically circumventing the fact that these goals were set at these thresholds in the first place. In other words: if SE wanted us to have more moderators when going live, they would simply have set the reputation requirement lower.

Regardless of all of this, it might be true that we need to vote more on questions and answers. There can be reasons for it, but *this* should not be one.

Comment: As I've understood it, voting is encouraged in general. The suggestion states that voting should be done where deserved, not only to raise rep. It's not unreasonable to have given as much rep in votes as you have received yourself, in most cases. We have a lot of users where that is not the case.

Comment: That's what I'm saying as well, @MeaningfulUsername. :)

Comment: I am quoting directly from a [canonical SE blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/): __"It’s only through voting that a class of editors, closers, and moderators can emerge to help run and govern the site. Voting is how site leadership forms."__ @LeeWhite I applaud your thoughtfulness and your caution, but I think the OP is framing this the right way. :)